Arduino Digispark ATtiny85 conditional logic not working
Expected Behavior:
I am attempting to use && or nested if statements to achieve the effect of two switches being required to close prior to an LED light (i.e., flip both switches), the LED turns on for 1 second, and then turns off.
Encountered Behavior:
It appears that no matter how I write the statement, if the SECOND if is true, the LED lights up.
Additional information:
The switches connect directly to ground when closed.
I have tried multiple conditional statements:

using &&: if (switch1 == LOW && switch2 == LOW) {LED code}
Nested if: if (switch1 == LOW) { if (switch2 == LOW) {LED code} }

I have tried multiple variable declarations:

int switch1 = 0; int switch2 = 1; (using integer representation of digispark pinout)
#define switch1 PB1

#define switch1 PB1
#define switch2 PB0

void setup()
{
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(switch1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(switch2, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  if (!digitalRead(switch1)) {
    if (!digitalRead(switch2)) {
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
      delay(1000); // wait for a second
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    }
  }

  else {
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    delay(1);
  }
}

My Digispark Attiny85 is attached to a breadboard, where it receives power through the 5V and ground pins on the Digispark board. PB0 and PB1 connect directly to ground when closed, otherwise I count on the pull-up resistors. PB2 is connected to an LED -> resistor -> ground. All components share the same 5V power supply and ground.


what happens if you change the second if statement to  if (false){?

@jsotola Nothing happens now when I connect to ground PB0, PB1, or both

@jsotola. One last issue. It is the SECOND if , that if true, turns LED on. That is, the first if is irrelevant for some reason and I cannot figure out why this is the case

make the first if (false) ... what happens then?

@jsotola, I think I answered below. Can you verify my reasoning?

I am confident I solved the problem and think I know why it occurs.
PB1 on the digispark Attiny85 has a built in LED. This LED is still active when I run my code. The LED is dim, but consuming power. My hypothesis is that is is consuming enough current to drive that pin low when digital_read is called on PB1. Therefore, PB1 always evaluates to true, because of the internal LED (despite the fact that input_pullup should drive it false by default).
Here is how I tested this hypothesis:

If I plug PB1 into 5v+, the internal LED gets brighter, and my project LED never lights up. i.e., my first if is now !true, so the conditional fails to execute.
If I recode to exclude PB1 and instead map to PB3, my code runs as intended.

All of this is to say, I think that even when you specify PB1 as input_pullup, it does not behave as expected because of the internal LED.
@jsotola, thank you for your kindness and patience. What do you think?

makes sense ... remove the external LED and use the internal LED instead ... use PB0 and PB2 for the switches

Good debugging effort. In the future, you can also just spam a bunch of Serial.print() in there to monitor if your switches work

@towe I am not sure I can do that with digispark, but I am new to this and will  let you know what I find out

You would appear to have the incorrect physical pins connected to the switches:

Pins 0 and 1 connect directly to ground when closed, otherwise I count on the pull-up resistors.

However:

PB0 is physical pin 5
PB1 is physical pin 6



I apologize for the sloppy language. The digispark has the pins labeled and what I meant to say is that I connected to the pins labeled PB0 and PB1 on the digispark. So, I have the pins labeled PB0 and PB1 on the digispark connected to ground when closed

@jmarywien please update your question with this new information

@jsotola. Thanks updated language and added schematic
